# AOT compilation in Angular 12

Tags: angular, build, aot, angular-aot

Angular documentation states:

```
 *Ahead-of-Time (AOT), which compiles your application and libraries at build time. This is the 
 default since Angular 9.*
```

So if I want to compile for **production** my Angular 12 application with AOT I just need to type **ng build** without adding **--prod** and without adding specific configuration neither in **angular.json** nor in **package.json**?

This is the **ng build** command insieme my package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
...
```

Thank for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly include the `--prod` command for production build - given that you're using the latest version of Angular i.e. v12 I gather.

The default angular.json file includes a profile section about the production build and you can leave it as it is.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Angular 12.0.0. Thank for your help

Comment: From you answer I didn't get if with 'ng build' command Angular 12 will compile with AOT without any specific configuration needed

Comment: @Matt - There is a configuration section within the angular.json file for production build process. This section includes a property called "aot". It's set to true by default which enables the AOT build.

Comment: There isn't any property call aot inside my angular.json. That's why I have this doubt

Comment: @Matt - that's strange! Newly created Angular app has the AOT property and its set to true. You can modify your angular.json file to include this flag. Please see the following Angular v12 app created from scratch here --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q4qs63?file=angular.json

Comment: In Angular 12 AOT is the default so the option is not even there on a newly created project.